# Assigning each element of an array (one at a time) to a variable for a specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I  have an array with a list of elements(users in this case ).I have a variable called currentBeneficiary. I want to assign each user to be a currentBeneficiary for a specific amount of time like 10m,then we move on to the next member of array and assign them to the variable(currentBeneficiary) for same amount of time so on. I have used SetInterval() and it assigns an element of the array to the variable just for 1s after the specified period of time.And as mentioned i just want the vice versa.How can i achieve this kindly?

```
const members = merrygoround.members
let currentbeneficiary
if(merrygoround.interval === "daily"){
 
function DelayArray(array, delegate, delay) {
var i = 0
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    delegate(array[i]);
    if (i++ >= array.length - 1)
        clearInterval(interval);
}, delay)

return interval

}
DelayArray(members, function(obj) {
currentbeneficiary = obj
console.log(`current beneficiary is ${currentbeneficiary}`)
},1000*60)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval mean process will wait a "delay" before run your logic, after that wait a "delay" again. I am not sure I understand your question. I guess you want the first user must run right the moment DelayArray call, so you just call the delegate function for the first user before run DelayArray, variable i will start with 1.